# EXIF image in php

Tags: php

I have a page that image gets uploaded to but the image are not the right way.
I know I need to use EXIF but I am new to this and lost where to start on this as it is in a while loop 
can any one help me

thx jason

here is my code

```
<section class ="box_1">
 <form id="evaluations" method="post" action="comments_page_add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`enter code here`

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Parent Entered</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>

</tr>
<?php
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="child[]" type="checkbox" id="child[]" value="<?PHP echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['given_name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['surname']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
}

?>
</table>

</section>
<section class ="box_3">
<?php
while($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results3)){
?>
<table width="100%" border="2"  bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr> 

<tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><img src='<?php echo $rows2['Photo_parth']; ?>' width='60%' height='150em'></td></tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="image[]" type="checkbox" id="image[]" value="<?PHP echo $rows2['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows2['id']; ?></td></tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows2['date']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows2['time']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}

?>

   </table>
</section>
```

Comment: `but the image are not the right way` And we should guess what is the right way or maybe you can explain?

Comment: the Image are on there side or on there head. I need to get the right orientation